# How do you calculate a circumference when given the diameter

Tags: vba, excel

I have to write code that will give me the circumference when I am given the diameter of 2 meters.

My code is written like this:

```
Sub WorksheetFunctionDemo3()

Debug.Print WorksheetFunction. Pi(2)

End sub
```

But it is coming up with an error. I know without the (2) it will give me the value of Pi, but I can't figure out how to multiply it by 2.

It is in VBA for Excel.

[image]

Comment: it would be great if u can link your code and put the language it is in the tags

Comment: `Debug.Print WorksheetFunction. Pi*2?` Then again, what language is this?!

Comment: "coming up with an error": What error is it?

Comment: I don't know of a function called NormDiinv, is that a typo in your code on the attached picture? I can see that `Debug.Print WorksheetFunction.Pi * 2` works in your picture

Comment: yes it was an error. and i was able to figure it out thanks! and yes that was a typo

Comment: Can I just get this straight: you post a question on how to multiply a value by 2, within the post you have an image of your code which multiplies a value by 2, and in your comments you say you figured out how to do it? I guess this is homework, so perhaps you could ask your teacher to cover making best use of external resources?

Comment: I emailed my teacher multiple times, he will not help. I'm sorry for trying to use whatever resource I could find for help. I'll make sure not to get help anymore.

Answer (score 0):

```
Debug.Print (2 * WorksheetFunction.Pi)
```